# NSString - remove all characters after last white space

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsstring

My string is `@"Hello, I am working as an ios developer"`

Now I want to remove all characters after word `"ios"`

Ultimately I want to remove all characters after last white space character.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Sample Code :**

```
NSString* str= @"Hello, I am working as an ios developer";

// Search from back to get the last space character
NSRange range= [str rangeOfString: @" " options: NSBackwardsSearch];

// Take the first substring: from 0 to the space character
NSString* finalStr = [str substringToIndex: range.location]; // @"Hello, I am working as an ios"
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Bhavin, but I think, better is using of [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] to determine whitespace characters.

```
    NSString* str= @"Hello, I am working as an ios developer";

    // Search from back to get the last space character
    NSRange range= [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] options:NSBackwardsSearch];

    // Take the first substring: from 0 to the space character
    NSString* finalStr = [str substringToIndex: range.location]; // @"Hello, I am working as an ios"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also Achieve this using REGEX

```
NSString* str= @"Hello, I am working as an ios developer";
NSString *regEx = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ios"];///Make a regex
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:regEx options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
{

    NSString *subStr=[str substringToIndex:(range.location+range.length)];
}
```

this will search for first "ios" keyword and will discard after words

Hope it will help.